# What is pack option in solution explorer?

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017

What is "Pack" option useful for ?

[image]

It seems that it does the same thing as Build.
The output is following

> 1>------ Build started: Project: KnockoutTest, Configuration: Debug
>   Any CPU ------ 1>KnockoutTest ->
>   C:\Users\path\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.0\KnockoutTest.dll
>   ========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

Comment: You are right, i updated question. It is C# asp.net core mvc project.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-pack?tabs=netcore2x

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The term “pack” comes from NuGet, where “packing” basically means that you create a NuGet package out of your project.

This is usually done using the NuGet command line, by calling [`nuget pack`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/tools/cli-ref-pack).

With .NET SDK based projects, e.g. ASP.NET Core, this functionality is also available through [`dotnet pack`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-pack?tabs=netcore2x) which makes the package creation process a bit simpler (by assuming many defaults, making this less customizable than `nuget pack`).

This is generally also what the “Pack” command does in the context menu in Visual Studio. Packing will usually involve building the project properly and then packing it into a `.nupkg` file. If you look at your project output, you should see a `KnockoutTest.nupkg` file as well.